# AngularJS not linking with MVC Model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

We are building a form within an ng-repeat tag. The ng-model does not seem to be linking with the MVC control model.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in favourites">
   <form ng-submit="Delete()" id="frmSpec">
       <input  ng-model="item.Description"/>
       <input  ng-model="item.Refno"/>
       <button type="submit"class="btn">{{item.Description}} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
   </form>
</li> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $scope.Delete = function () {
              var url = '/List/DeleteFavourites/';
              $http.post(url, $scope.formData)
                    .success(function (data) {
                    });
          };</script>
```

Within the MVC controller

```
        public ActionResult DeleteFavourites(Models.MyModel mm, string ButtonType)
        {

        }
```

This issue is that mm is being returned as Null

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked what is being actually sent?

Comment: Hi, we have used fiddler, and there is no data being sent back.. is there an issue with out the data is bound?

Comment: If the data wasn't sent - then you have issues with JS and mvc for this question is irrelevant isn't it? Btw, what is `$scope.formData`?